# Spring Data Rest search by keyword

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to find the solution for implementing search by keyword. Final API should look like `/persons/search?keyword=test`. The search should check several columns of persons table `(firstName, lastName, school, ...)`.

In the result list, I need to have the list of persons which contains keyword at least in one column.

What will be the best solution to implement that by using Spring Data Rest?

Comment: use specification eg: http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @theLearner, yes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@Query` annotation on a repository, you can do something like this:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Persons, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Persons where LOWER(p.firstname) like :key%"
            + " or LOWER(p.lastname) like :key%" )
    public List<Person> searchBy(@Param("word") String key);
}
```

**NOTE**: I did a similar thing, but I do not have the exact code right now, so just check out the syntax, but what I was able to achieve with this was the ability to search on multiple columns with a single key.